# Multiple RSS feeds scroller in one sidebar

Tags: customization

How can i have multiple RSS feeds scroller in one sidebar. I want the RSS feeds of CNN, BBC, google news, USA today etc, all at the same time, is it possible to duplicate an RSS scrolling widget?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the latest version of WordPress, all default widgets (including the RSS widget that ships with WordPress) are multi-instance.  This means you can drag multiple instances of the same widget onto the sidebar and have each one contain different content.

So without knowing exactly *which* "RSS scrolling widget" you're using, I can only speak in general terms ... but **yes**, typically you can have duplicate RSS widgets in the sidebar that list news items from different sources.

Comment: I am using ANT news ticker for instance, i dont find its duplicate anywhere in my widgets section, how would i duplicate it otherwise?

Comment: If it's using the old (pre WordPress 2.8) method for creating a widget, then you can't.  Multi-instance widgets were created with WP 2.8 when we switched from procedurally defining everything to extending the `WP_Widget` class.  Your best options would be to a) Contact the author and ask for an update b) Attempt to update the plugin to the new framework yourself or c) Find another system with the same features that does support multi-instance.

Comment: @MsManiya: It seems [ANT is no longer supported](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-accessible-news-ticker-ant-horizontal-news-ticker). Also, it used a script for scrolling the text [that also doesn't work on Mac OS X](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2006/03/23/return-of-the-dreaded-dhtml-news-scroller/).

Answer (score 0):

is the question about a scrolling content or the "multiple part" .

My guess is that If you want to have a scroll box , add a regular text widget where you add the links and then you need to wrap your links around an overflow:scroll - here is an example - of course u can play with the css to make it "nice"

`<div style="height:120px;width:150px;overflow:scroll;">
    As you can see, once there's enough text in this box, the box will grow scroll bars... that's why we call it a scroll box! You could also place an image into the scroll box.
    </div>`

Answer (score 0):

The plugin RSSImport has an pagination function and can include feeds in the sidebar, via Widget, Shortcode or PHP function. You can use Yahoo Pipes for create an feed form many different feeds and include this via plugin. Maybe this is an solution for your requirements.

Comment: thank you very much, but its not scrolling :( and i need a scrolling one, otherwise its just perfect for me